# Laravel 5 route groups `prefix and `as` and resource controllers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel's route groups to try and stop duplication within my Routes file.

I have one main group, `frontend`. This has the `namespace` `Frontend` and `as` `frontend.`

Nested within that group, is another group. This group has the `prefix` `account` which appends `/account/` to each route. It also has `as` `account.`.

The routes inside the nested group, I'd expect to be:

1. `frontend.account.home`
2. `frontend.account.order.show`
3. `frontend.account.order.index`

Instead I get:

1. `frontend.account.home`
2. `frontend.account.account.order.index`
3. `frontend.account.account.order.show`

Code:

```
Route::group(['as' => 'frontend.', 'namespace' => 'Frontend'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'account', 'as' => 'account.', 'namespace' => 'Account'], function () {
        Route::get('home', [
            'as'   => 'home',
            'uses' => 'Home\Controller@get'
        ]);

        Route::resource('order', 'Order\Controller', ['except' => [
            'create',
            'store',
            'update',
            'destroy',
            'edit',
        ]]);
    });
});
```

Comment: Try by Removing `'namespace' => 'Account'` from inner `Route::group` which has prefix as account

Comment: But then that'd stop the namespace working? The two conflicting options are `prefix` and `as`.

Comment: remove the 'as' => 'account.' from your Route::group

Answer (score 1):

Since your excepting almost every routes from the `Route::resource` method, why not create 2 single routes for `index` and `show` like so:

```
// in your routes file, within your nested group :
Route::get('order', ['as' => 'order.index', 'uses' => 'Order\Controller@index' ]);
Route::get('order/{id}', ['as' => 'order.show', 'uses' => 'Order\Controller@show' ]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the order route resource is only one example, there are many more that will have all of the standard routes.